# How to convert json data into flow chart

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowchart

I am trying to make a flow chart out kind of diagram from the below JSON data. There will be no condition

```
var a = [
            {
            "selector": "mark",
            "color": "#1b1f23"
        }
    ,
        {
            "selector": "legend",
            "color": "inherit"
        }
    ,

        {
            "selector": "::-webkit-input-placeholder",
            "color": "inherit"
        }
    ,

        {
            "selector": "body",
            "color": "#24292e"
        }

];
```

I am not getting any free source to do the same . Please help ..

The output should look like this :

[image: this]

Answer (score 3):

while I'm working on RESTful API I found this chrome extension and it was helpful and it can convert the JSON Object response in the browser to a flow chart by choosing the chart tab in the browser
[image: tab chart]

here where you can download it:

[JSON Viewer Pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer-pro/eifflpmocdbdmepbjaopkkhbfmdgijcc)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [d3.js](https://d3js.org/). It is a javascript library and you can use it to create any shape with dataset. You can create different shapes based upon the selector property and accomplish your task.